# CouchDB change Database directory

Tags: linux, sockets, couchdb

I am trying to change the directory of the couch database. I am using a python script to import a csv file to the CouchDB. Script is running ok. Here it is just in case:

```
from couchdbkit import Server, Database
from couchdbkit.loaders import FileSystemDocsLoader
from csv import DictReader
import sys, subprocess, math, os

def parseDoc(doc):
    for k,v in doc.items():
        if (isinstance(v,str)):
            #print k, v, v.isdigit()
            # #see if this string is really an int or a float
            if v.isdigit()==True: #int
                doc[k] = int(v)
            else: #try a float
                try:
                    if math.isnan(float(v))==False:
                        doc[k] = float(v) 
                except:
                    pass            
    return doc

def upload(db, docs):
    db.bulk_save(docs)
    del docs
    return list()

def uploadFile(fname, dbname):
  #connect to the db
  theServer = Server()
  db = theServer.get_or_create_db(dbname)

  #loop on file for upload
  reader = DictReader(open(fname, 'rU'), dialect = 'excel')

  docs = list()
  checkpoint = 100
  i = 0
  for doc in reader:
    newdoc = parseDoc(doc) 
    docs.append(newdoc)

    if len(docs)%checkpoint==0:
      docs = upload(db,docs)
      i += 1
      print 'Number : %d' %i

  #don't forget the last batch        
  docs = upload(db,docs)

if __name__=='__main__':
  x = '/media/volume1/Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv'
  filename = x
  dbname = 'test'
  uploadFile(filename, dbname)
```

I saw plenty posts on how to change the directory for appending the database. If I leave the /etc/couchdb/local.ini as it is (original after installation) the script is appending data to the default directory /var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1/. When I modify the local.ini to store the database to another disk:

> database_dir = /media/volume1 
>   view_index_dir = /media/volume1

and after the reboot of the CouchDB service I get this error :

> restkit.errors.RequestError: socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I have checked the open sockets (couchdb uses 5984 as default) and it is not opened. But I get no errors when I start CouchDB service. 
Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: i would check you new directory and make sure couchdb has ownership of it:   `ls -al [new dir]`    `sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb [new_dir]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error may be due to you have changed the directory location in Local.ini but when you are trying to make new connection to existing database, it cannot find it there.

So move the database_name.couch file to new location which you can put in local.ini and then try to make a connection. I think this should work.